Error message when trying to access other spreadsheets in onEdit()
I'm trying to grab data from another spreadsheet through onEdit(). I'm getting the following error message:
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
My script is tied to a spreadsheet (not on the cloud) is there a way to use sheets API authorization to bypass this? I haven't used sheets api before and got really lost in the documentation for oauth. In my project overview in scripts it looks like I do have this oauth scope already added, so I'm not sure why it's telling me I don't. Picture attached is the oauth scopes for my project for which i'm getting the error message.

I tried running my function in scripts to give authorization manually but it didn't seem to help. I also tried grabbing the data in a separate function that gets called by my onEdit function but that didn't work either.

The onedit is a simple trigger.  It cannot perform actions that require permission.  Chose  to use an installable trigger instead.


onEdit.restrictions()


It is not possible to access other spreadsheets from a process that is started by a simple trigger. So you can do the following:
A) Rename onEdit() for example to myOnEdit().
B) Set the myOnEdit() function to run as a trigger on the spreadsheet editing event:
